# How to Set attr_accessor for Question Mark Methods in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I got the error below when I initialize a MyBox.

```
NameError: invalid attribute name `isClocked?'
```

Below is my model file.

```
class MyBox < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_reader :isClocked?
end
```

`schema.rb` contains

```
t.boolean  "isClocked?"
```

It seems that it is invalid to use `?` mark in attr_accessor. But my attribute contains a `?`. How can I access it?

Comment: What do you mean your attribute contains a `?`? Did you actually set your database column name up to contain a question mark?

Comment: I got `t.boolean  "isClocked?"` in `schema.rb`.

Comment: You really shouldn't. You've deviated pretty heavily from both Ruby and Rails conventions, and you're going to wind up fighting the framework. Unless you have a **very** good reason for requiring that column name, you should name the column `clocked` and be done with it. Don't use `is_` prefixes in Ruby, and don't use `camelCase` in Ruby or Rails. use `underscore_case`.

Comment: Thanks. I got your notification. You say don't use `camelCase` in any occasion in a rails app?

Answer (score 1):

In your case you should:

1. define field as:

   ```
   t.boolean :clocked
   ```
2. remove `attr_reader` because AR creates it automagically.
3. use `clocked` or `clocked?` field in your model to access field value:

   ```
   my_box = MyBox.first

   p my_box.clocked?
   p my_box.clocked
   ```

Comment: AR automatically creates it then when to use `attr_accessor`?

Comment: Yes, you shouldn't define `clocked` in your model. Just define it in your migration.

Comment: [Here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#creating-active-record-models) is a example.